# Added A Touch FeedBack to Custom View

Tags: android, android-custom-view, touch-feedback

How can I add a touch feedback like a ripple to my Custom View?

I could detect the Touch Events but I want simple like a ripple to happen when my custom view is touched. is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to play a xml animation for your view.

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.my_amazing_ripple_effect);

myCustomView.startAnimation(anim);
```

You can find many xml animations all over the internet, but you can also create your own (which I highly recommend).

Let me know if this helped.

---

UPDATE:

Sample code:

```
View myView = ...some view; // grab your view here

myView.setOnClickListener( v -> { // this is a lambda expression. It is only used to shorten the code and improve its legibility. You could also use myView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { }

    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.my_amazing_ripple_effect);

    myView.startAnimation(anim);

});
```

Comment: Can you give some sample code please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry it took me some time to get back to you. Haven't really tried this yet because of some circumstances. Does Android View's like buttons does the same thing? I tried digging into the Android Button code but cant actually find out how they do it.

Comment: Yes. Android Button extends TextView, which extends View. As such, they implement all their functions and then some. You can view the code directly in Android Studio. Just press Ctrl + click on a class (Cmd if you're on mac).

Comment: I'll take your word for it then. I'll go check the code again when I have time. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I could help. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'`, Place your custom Widget inside `MaterialRippleLayout`, [Here](https://github.com/balysv/material-ripple)

```
  <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.3"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                app:mrl_rippleColor="#80FF5722"
                app:mrl_rippleDimension="10dp"
                app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
                app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">
            <com.your.custome.view
               />
            </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>
```

You can use this programmatically also

```
MaterialRippleLayout.on(view)
           .rippleColor(Color.BLACK)
           .create();
```

Comment: I actually want how it's implemented. But thank you.. I'll read this library to learn how ripples are made. :)

Comment: @ArchieQuiñones you can also use this programmatically by passing view instance.